# curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: php, laravel

I create laravel project by using command "omposer create-project laravel/laravel reward_system". Then I can't create the project it shows error "In CurlDownloader.php line 372:

curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [ [ []]]"

I need a help!
I try to find solution in 2 dasy ago but still not resolve.

Comment: Which version of PHP and Composer do you use? Are you facing any other networking problem? Also, are you sure the error is directly related to Laravel itself?